# How to SELECT the last 10 rows of an SQL table which has no ID field?

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an MySQL table with 25000 rows.

This is an imported CSV file so I want to look at the last ten rows to make sure it imported everything.

However, since there is no ID column, I can't say:

```
SELECT * FROM big_table ORDER BY id DESC
```

**What SQL statement would show me the last 10 rows of this table?**

The structure of the table is simply this:

```
columns are: A, B, C, D, ..., AA, AB, AC, ... (like Excel)
all fields are of type TEXT
```

Comment: Define "last".  In most SQL implementations there is no inherent order...

Comment: show the structure of your table, please.

Comment: Add the rownumber from the file as a column.

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but why don't use just add an AUTO_INCREMENT column to your schema? (You'll still be able to import the CSV as-is.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQL tables have no implicit ordering, the order has to come from the data.
Perhaps you should add a field to your table (e.g. an int counter) and re-import the data.

However that will only give the order of the import and not the data. If your data has no ordering you have to find out how to add it.

**EDIT:** you say

> ...to make sure it imported everything.

What's wrong with using row count?

Comment: +1 - OP should think of his table like a file folder full of papers.  They all have information on them, but without a date on each page, which is "first"?  Which is "last"?

Comment: Indeed; you're going to have to define "last" in your data before you can ask this question. An auto_increment field would probably be the best solution; that should end up in the database in the same order as the CSV file. Though I don't suppose it's technically guaranteed, depending on the importer.

Comment: but isn't it true if I do a SELECT * FROM big_table, it would give me the rows in the same order that they were added? If this is the case I could write a little 3-liner to do this in some language but I would think there would be a way for SQL to do it, such as some kind of `ORDER BY NATURAL_ORDER` or something like that.

Comment: by "last" I just mean the last row imported

Comment: @Edward: it will only give you the rows in the physical ordering of the primary key (unless the data is clustered on another field) and even then the order of the data returned by the SQL engine is not *guaranteed* to be in that order.

Comment: @Edward Tanguay - your `SELECT * FROM big_table` probably will give you rows in that order, but it's not a guarantee.  If you don't specify an order you get rows in whatever order your RDBMS pulls  the data pages.

Comment: No, there's no serious guarantee about the order of a `SELECT` without `ORDER BY`. If you're willing to accept whatever order your database applies to the rows, extract the row count and use `SELECT * FROM big_table LIMIT 10 OFFSET {count-10}`. But really, you should define what order you intend to use (say, a timestamp that represents the time when the row was inserted).

Comment: @EdwardTanguay The fact is that MySQL generally keeps things "well sorted". The effect is that when you do a `SELECT`, even without an `ORDER BY`, your rows will have a sensible order. At least pretty much all my tables look that way in MySQL. However, when I use PostgreSQL, that's a quite different story. The order is generally the order in which you added the rows. That's a different philosophy. PostgreSQL inserts are really fast and if you use indexes, the reads will be fast too (however, more indexes and slower the `INSERT` becomes...)

Answer (score 27):

All the answers here are better, but just in case...
There is a way of getting 10 last added records. (thou this is quite unreliable :) ) still
you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET N-10
```

N - should be the total amount of rows in the table (SELECT count(*) FROM table).   You can put it in a single query using prepared queries but I'll not get into that.

Comment: Offset does not seem to be working in mysql. Are you sure about syntax?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that MySQL supports OFFSET. If not all the websites I've created in last 5 years are in deep trouble :D
Most probably the reason why it doesn't work for you, is that you haven't read my answer to the end. You have to substitute N in the query with a number of rows in the table. So a the end query should look like SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1579-10 or something like that. And as i sad it is possible to get this in one query using prepared queries. However for this answer is not about MySQL syntax but about the way you can do this.

Comment: If offset doesn't take any time for sql this is the perfect solution but does it?

Answer (score 22):

Select from the table, use the ORDER BY **__** DESC to sort in reverse order, then limit your results to 10.

```
SELECT * FROM big_table ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `ORDER BY DESC` option, then put it back in the original order:

```
(SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you, the other answers do not take into consideration that the data will be retrieved in reverse order without the extra ordering.

Comment: In the question it's clear that there is NO id column

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM big_table ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing a `LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'` operation, the easiest way to see if all the lines went in is to check `show warnings();`  If you load the data into an empty or temporary table, you can also check the number of rows that it has after the insert.

Answer (score 3):

**If you have not tried the following command**

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM big_table ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I see it's working when I execute the command

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerId DESC;
```

in the ***Try it yourself*** command window of https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

Comment: This does not answer the original question because it assumes that the table has an id column which can be used for ordering.

Can you provide a way to query a table (well, its last lines) in its **insertion order** without relying on an ID?

Comment: Oh, my bad! I haven't noticed that you have no ID column there!
Solution to this problem might lie in making use of the LIMIT command.
Try the command: 
> SELECT * FROM big_table LIMIT 24990,10

Comment: One more query one can execute, only as I find it's working now:

**Declare** a parameter `x` and **set** it's value to zero.
` SET @x=0; `

Then you have to add an additional column **_rank_** to your answer as:
`SELECT aColumnName, @x := @x+1 as rank FROM big_table;`
_see what the result is?_

Now we can just put this query into our next query as:
`SELECT aColumnName FROM (SELECT *, @x := @x+1 as rank FROM big_table) AS P ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 0,10;`

**Hope this works for you.** :)

Answer (score 2):

executing a count(*) query on big data is expensive. I think using

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT n
```

where `n` is your number of rows per page is better and lighter

Comment: Ah...ORDER BY of a huge table is faster then SELECT COUNT(*)?

Answer (score 2):

That can be done using the limit function, this might not seem new but i have added something.The code should go:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 100,10;
```

for the above case assume that you have 110 rows from the table and you want to select the last ten, 100 is the row you want to start to print(if you are to print), and ten shows how many rows you want to pick from the table.
For a more precised way you can start by selecting all the rows you want to print out and then you grab the last row id if you have an id column(i recommend you put one) then subtract ten from the last id number and that will be where you want to start, this will make your program to function autonomously and for any number of rows, but if you write the value directly i think you will have to change the code every time data is inserted into your table.I think this helps.Pax et Bonum.

Answer (score 1):

you can with code select 10 row from end of table.
select * from (SELECT * FROM table1 order by id desc  LIMIT 10) as table2 order by id"

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many rows to expect, I would create a separate temporary table in your database of the expected structure, append into that, then check the count... Once you are good with that, then you can massage that data before appending it into your final production table.

Answer (score 0):

A low-tech approach: Doing this with SQL might be overkill. According to your question you just need to do a one-time verification of the import.

Why not just do: SELECT * FROM ImportTable

and then scroll to the bottom of the results grid and visually verify the "last" few lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve last 10 records from sql use LIMIT.
Suppose the data base contains 20 records.Use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 10,20;
```

where 10,20 is the offset value.Where 10 represent starting limit and 20 is the ending limit.

i.e 20 -10=10 records