# How to write an SQL query to get records based on the order they were entered in?(no date col)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL query that returns records in the order in which they were entered in to a table.

I can't add a column to the table or change the table in any way. I can `insert into` and `select` from the table.

Say I execute three insert queries like

```
  insert into x values(a,1);
  insert into x values(d,4);
  insert into x values(u,42);
```

when I select from the table `x` I need to get the records in this order.

- a  1
- d  4
- u  42

The table has only two columns, both have nothing to do with date.

Comment: What Database system?  MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc? Please edit this into your question.

Comment: Also, please provide information about the table. Does it have some `createdAt` column or an `id` that gets increased for every insertation?

Comment: what does the table stucture look like? is there a PK with Auto-increments? is there a date-added field? etc

Comment: I'm guessing your question is very similar to [one I answered a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714975/how-to-select-the-last-10-rows-of-an-sql-table-which-has-no-id-field/4714994#4714994).

Comment: If there are no other columns in x like an auto-increment/indentiy/timestamp then you can't. The designer of the database has not allowed this. Can you add another table and a trigger?

Comment: Edited  the question as per the instructions in the comments.

Comment: You can't. The order returned is not deterministic without an `order by` clause, and you don't have any thing to order by

Comment: @Jodrell - Unfortunately "I can't add a column to the table or change the table in any way". So he won't be able to add a trigger either. Basically there's no way to do what he's asking without a change to the database.

Comment: This depends on your Database engine. Some DBMS have an internal row_id as a default ORDER BY which essentially gives the rows in order of insertion.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it without changing the table in some way.

When you select data from a table the order in which it is returned is non-deterministic on all the sql database engines I know and certainly in MSSQL server 2000+. To get the rows in a defined order you must include an `ORDER BY` clause and there is nothing you can specify to give the desired order.

Since you cannot change the schema, then this is game over.

---

Okay, (almost) nothing is impossible. You could periodically analyse the physical database file for changes and decode those into the information you require but, this would likely fail when multiple rows were inserted by one transaction.

I doubt you have the access or the inclination to do that.

Comment: +1 for the idea to analyze the database file!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The order returned is not deterministic without an `order by` clause, and you don't have any thing to order by